# Custom Function on Multiple Variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am calculating the average after centering a variable. By centering it implies subtracting the mean of the variable from its original variable. I am using `dplyr` package. I am able to do it for one variable via mutate() function. How can I do the same for multiple variables using mutate?

```
set.seed(1)      # for reproducible example
train <- data.frame(X1=sample(1:100,100),
                 X2=1e6*sample(1:100,100),
                 X3=1e-6*sample(1:100,100))

library(dplyr)
train %>%  mutate(center = X1-mean(X1)) %>% 
  summarise(round(mean(center),4))
```

Comment: You can use `mutate_all`

Comment: I am unable to get rid of X1 in the function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you are giving a fake example, but `mean(x-mean(x))` is obviously 0 (regardless of `x`) and can give a different value only for floating point precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for : (add `na.rm = TRUE` is required inside `mean()`

```
library(dplyr)
train %>% summarise_all(function(x) mean(x - mean(x)))
#  X1 X2            X3
#   0  0 -3.251647e-21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
train %>% mutate_each(funs(((function(x){x-mean(x)})(.)))) %>% 
summarise_each(funs(mean(.), na.rm = TRUE)))
```